# How to only emit from text-field after positive validation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-text-field` with validation rules, which emits something on blur.

```
<v-text-field
    :rules="validationRules"
    @blur="emitFunction"
></v-text-field>
```

Is there a way to only call the `emitFunction` if the validation passes?

Comment: Are you using vuetify 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using Vuetify 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in [v-form](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms), and track if the form is valid with `v-model`

```
const isValid = ref(false)
function emitIfValid() {
  if (isValid.value) emitFunction()
}
```

```html
<v-form v-model="isValid">
  <v-text-field
    :rules="validationRules"
    @blur="emitIfValid"
  />
</v-form>
```